# No Such FIle or Directory while running CPP test on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am new in **cocos2d**. I am following this site to start with environment setup and run the first program.

http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Android

After setting up the environment I am executing this code from cmd.

I am running `setup.py` command from cmd.

**The following outcomes appears on the cmd.**

> Setting up cocos2d-x...
>   ->Check environment variable COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT   ->Search for environment variable COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT...
>       ->COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT is found : D:\setup\cocos setup\cocos2d-x-3.3\tools\cocos2d-console\bin
>
> ->Check environment variable COCOS_X_ROOT   ->Search for environment variable COCOS_X_ROOT...
>       ->COCOS_X_ROOT is found : D:\setup\cocos setup\cocos2d-x-3.3
>
> ->Check environment variable COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT   ->Search for environment variable COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT...
>       ->COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT is found : D:\setup\cocos setup\cocos2d-x-3.3\templates
>
> ->Configuration for Android platform only, you can also skip and manually edit your environment variables
>
> ->Check environment variable NDK_ROOT   ->Search for environment variable NDK_ROOT...
>       ->NDK_ROOT is found : D:\setup\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\android-ndk-r9d
>
> ->Check environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT   ->Search for environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT...
>       ->ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is found : D:\setup\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
>
> ->Check environment variable ANT_ROOT   ->Search for environment variable ANT_ROOT...
>       ->ANT_ROOT is found : D:\setup\cocos setup\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin
>
> Please restart the terminal or restart computer to make added system
>   variables take effect

And finally I am executing below command.

**android-build.py -p 17 cpp-tests**

*It gives me the below mentioned error.*

> D:\setup\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\android-ndk-r9d\ndk-build
>   -j2 NDK_DE BUG=1 NDK_MODULE_PATH=D:\setup\cocos setup\cocos2d-x-3.3\build..;D:\setup\cocos 
>   setup\cocos2d-x-3.3\build../external;D:\setup\cocos
>   setup\cocos2d-x-3.3\build\ ../cocos NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.8 -C
>   D:\setup\cocos setup\cocos2d-x-3.3\build.
>   .\tests/cpp-tests/proj.android make.exe: *** D:\setup\cocos: No such
>   file or directory.  Stop. Build dynamic library for project [
>   D:\setup\cocos setup\cocos2d-x-3.3\build..\
>   tests/cpp-tests/proj.android ] fails!

I am stuck at this point.

Comment: "D:\setup\cocos: No such file or directory." ... sounds like a path with a space in between? perhaps an incorrect search path? Those are common issues with cocos2d-x unfortunately, just do a search.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Question edited for more understanding of query. Please help me what should I do at this point. I am new to cocos2d-x

Comment: change your path from `D:\setup\cocos setup` to `D:\setup\cocos-setup` by renaming the folder. Cocos2d-x doesn't like spaces in path names leading up to its installation

Comment: thats right mate. you saved me. but After renaming the folder name I am getting the same path of ant_root. but its now changed by me. So how can I update the path of ant_root

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Can you please answer this question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32437400/1395259